# The option on PyCharm Mac "Reveal in Finderl" what is in PyCharm for Windows

Tags: windows, python, pycharm

I am learning Python watching tutorials of Mosh. There he shows an option to add a `xl` file on pychram project using the option "Reveal in Finder" but I can't find it on my windows machine Pycharm IDE.
Can anyone help me to find it?

His tutorial image: [image]

My IDE image: [image]

Please help me find the option.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open in Explorer to navigate to where you downloaded that file then copy and paste it into the project area.  This will make it appear there.

Answer (score 2):

PyCharm on the tutorial image is older than yours I guess (also a different OS). Try "Open In" menu option.

[image]